# Type Error when Accessing and returning objects arrays inside objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to return the data inside each array in an object.

This is my Json:

```
 "student_clubs": { // brought in as object
      "art": { // object
        "illustration": ["Done"], // Array
        "design": ["Done"] // Array
      },
      "sports": { // object 
        "Basketball": ["Incomplete"], // Array
        "Hockey": ["Done"]  // Array
      }
    },
```

I'm trying to display it like this:

```
art:
illustration: done       design: done

sports:
Basketball: Incomplete   Hockey: Done
```

my jsx:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';


const ClubsPropTypes = {
    student_clubs: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    student_grades: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

class Clubs extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const StudentClubs = this.props.student_clubs;
    const Grades = this.props.grades;


    return (
      <div className="">
            {(StudentClubs.art || []).map(art => (
                    <div className="row">
                        <ul>
                            <p>art</p>
                            <li>illustration: {art.illustration}</li>
                            <li>design: {art.design}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                ))}
            ... same code for sports (seems repetitive)
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Clubs.propTypes = ClubsPropTypes;

module.exports = Clubs;
```

Right now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: (StudentClubs.art || []).map is not a function`. Why is that? How can I fix this? Also is there a better way to loop through these objects? :\

Comment: art is an object not an array, you need to use Object.keys() to convert it into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StudentClubs.art` is an object so you cant use it with map.

You can loop over an object using `Object.keys()` which returns an array of the object keys, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

You can loop over an object keys like:

```
Object.keys(myobject).map((key) => {
   // do stuff with myobject[key]
})
```

Or using for `in`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

eg:

```
for (let key in myobject) {
  if (myobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // do stuff with myobject[key]
  }
}
```

So then you can loop over the different clubs and for each of those clubs loop over their keys - display the key name and the list of values (Eg. "done").

If you can, adjust your JSON so that `student_clubs` is an array of objects and each of those is an array of objects containing the sub category string and a status string.
You dont need an array for Done / Incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

In your json art property is not an array, is an object, and objects has not the map function.
I don't understand why you might want to have an array to specify the state of the subproperty (sport or art). 
I would do as follows:

```
"student_clubs": [{
  "art":[
    {
      "discipline":"illustration",
      "status: "Done"
    },
    {
      "discipline:"Design",
      "status":"Done"
    }
  ],
  "sports":[
    {
      "discipline":"Basketball",
      "status":"Incomplete"
    },
    {
      "discipline":"Hockey",
      "status":"whatever"
    }  
  ]
]}
```

So now you can map througth each club, and inside each club you can map througth each "discipline" and do whatever you want in an easier way I think.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the json response.